# WPF Print text and images in one document

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, printing

I want to print a document that has text and images in it. I'm using a FlowDocument with tables and BlockUIContainers. In visual studio the image shows up but when I want to print the image section at runtime it is blank

```
<BlockUIContainer>
      <Grid>
          <Image 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Source="/Resources/company.jpg"
                Height="97"
                Width="184"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
      </Grid>
</BlockUIContainer>

 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
     if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
            printDialog.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowdocument).DocumentPaginator, "Flow Document Print Job");
     }
 }
```

Is there any reason to this behaviour? With any solution?

I was thinking that I have to put everything in a Canvas and after that I will do the printVisual function?